# Is there any way to use adsense in javafx 2.x webview

Tags: javafx-2, adsense

I created a simply html page include css and js.

When the page is using in the webview How i can add adsense ? Does AdSense work fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) is just a html viewer.  There is no reason why it would not work with [Google AdSense](http://www.google.com/adsense/).  Adsense generates html ads which should be viewable in a WebView.

1. Create the appropriate html for including Adsense in a document by following [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181947&topic=29033&ctx=topic).
2. Load your html in a standard browser like Chrome and ensure that advertisements are displaying correctly there.
3. Once your advertisements are displaying correctly in Chrome, then load the same html into WebView - it should work fine.